# Not able to select a checkbox using selenium

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

I have a readymade code and i'm trying to write tests for it using selenium. The code contains two or more than two checkboxes in following format with different ids like;

```
1. <input type="checkbox" id="8933059checkitem0">

2. <input type="checkbox" id="8933059checkitem1">

....
```

I'm using following xpath expression to grab the topmost checkbox :

```
"/html//div[@class='xyz']//input[@type='checkbox']"
```

Even placing '[1]' after the above xpath expression is giving no results. I'm looking for a xpath expression using which i can grab the first checkbox only.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your XPath expression looks fine. Are you sure that the first  `div[@class='xyz']` is the correct one? If you are using Chrome browser, you can validate your expression by open devtool, go to console, enter $x("your-expression") ;

Comment: Is the checkbox is inside `iframe`?

Comment: @Shubham Gupta Which language your are using. and also check if there is frame then get frame first and switch on frame than get.

Comment: Try to enclose the expression before choosing the first item: `(/html//div[@class='xyz']//input[@type='checkbox'])[1]`. If you use `[1]` alone, in most cases it grabs all children residing on the first level, not the first item.

Comment: Checkbox is not inside any iframe and and @Honza comment helped me in resolving this issue. Enclosing the expression before choosing the first item solved the issue.

Comment: Ok, I will post that as the answer, please, mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to enclose the expression before choosing the first item:

```
(/html//div[@class='xyz']//input[@type='checkbox'])[1]
```

or

```
(//input[@type='checkbox'])[position()=1 and ancestor::div[@class='xyz']]
```

If you use `[1]` alone, in most cases it grabs all first children, not the very first child alone (as expected).

Actually, positional predicates are often misunderstood. They don't select items relative to their parents, they celect items within the sequence being processed.